# XAML set datagrid to top 90% of grid, buttons to bottom 10 % all in a tabitem

Tags: xaml, datagrid, grid, mahapps.metro, tabitem

I have a TabItem which I want to display a DataGrid (MahApps.Metro) in the upper 90% of it and 2 buttons I want to display at the bottom 10% of it. This works when the window is fully enlarged, but when it is not, the scrollviewer is not visible and the controls and elements go off screen. Please help, I've been stuck for hours! Here is my code so far:

```
<TabItem Header="Queue" FontSize="15">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="77*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="24*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <DataGrid x:Name="songdatagrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SongInfo}" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                <DataGrid.Columns >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="songinfocolumn" Header="Song Info" Width=".6*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding songInfo.Text}" Uid="{Binding SongInfo.Uid}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Double click to open song in Youtube." MouseLeftButtonDown="tb_MouseLeftButtonDown5" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="requestercolumn" Header="Requester" Width=".18*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding songReq.Text}" Uid="{Binding songReq.Uid}" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Double click to open requester's Twitch page." MouseLeftButtonDown="tb_MouseLeftButtonDown6" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="moveupcolumn" Header="Move Up" Width=".12*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="35" Height="35" Uid="{Binding moveUp.Uid}" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Click="moveup" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to move this song up in the list.">
                                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_arrow_up}" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="deletecolumn" Header="Remove" Width=".12*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Width="35" Height="35" Uid="{Binding delete.Uid}" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Click="deleteSong" ToolTipService.ToolTip="Click to remove song from the list.">
                                    <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}">
                                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_delete}" />
                                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                                    </Rectangle>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" x:Name="refresh" IsDefault="True" Background="White" Content="Refresh" Click="Button_Click" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button Style="{DynamicResource SquareButtonStyle}" x:Name="clear" IsDefault="True" Background="White" Content="Clear List" Click="clearlist" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
```

I had to add this to the top to get the Metro horizontal scrollbar working on the tabholder. Other than this, there are just more tabitems.

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabholder" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightBlue"
        SelectionChanged="TabControl_SelectionChanged" >
    <TabControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabControl">
            <StackPanel>
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                    <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                          Panel.ZIndex ="1" 
                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Grid.Row="0"
                          IsItemsHost="true"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TabControl.Template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StackPanel` and the other `Grid` panels you have in there are redundant and causing your issues. Also your fixed `Width` & `Height` in templates that have their own set size attributes for things like Height are going to give unwanted results. You should only need something like this to accomplish your goal.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="9*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">...</DataGrid>

    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Button 1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button 2"/>

</Grid>
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the layout looks as it should now but when I have more data cells in the datagrid, it just flys off of the screen forever. Is there anyway to set the datagrid's maxheight to that 90% of the tabitem?

Comment: @Edude15000 I may need a visual example of what you mean by flys off screen forever. Generally, if your DataGrid is in a Grid parent with star sizing, then it should be constrained to the parent boundaries defined by the parent Grid and invoke `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` by default to have the `ScrollViewer` already built into the DataGrid template provide scrolling when necessary.

Comment: Here is what it looks like at normal (small) size: [SMALL SIZE](http://imgur.com/a/pE06R)

Here is what it looks like when fully maximized: [MAXIMIZED](http://imgur.com/a/7Av7L)

It flys out of the window and doesn't have a vertical scrollbar even through I set the VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

Comment: @Edude15000 Ok so that looks like you may have more going on further up the tree. For starters put VerticalAlignment="Stretch" on your DataGrid, your VerticalScrollBarVisibility declaration shouldn't even be required and if it was you would need to hit it with the attached property `ScrollViewer.VerticalBarVisibility` instead of just as a dependency property. However I would still ask If this DataGrid and it's parent Grid are actually Children of other layout stuff going on higher in the layout tree? That's what would more potentially cause the cutoff you see.

Comment: In order for Metro Tabholder to work with the scrollbar, I have to use the code I added up top ^^ Other than this, there are just other tabitems.

Comment: @Edude15000 Aha... there's your culprit amigo. Ditch that `StackPanel` parent you have that ContentPresenter and stuff in and use a `Grid` with rows (Height="*" on the second row that your contentpresenter would sit in) and you should be golden....StackPanel doesn't actually behave as a boundary invoking panel. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The StackPanel was causing the issues, everything works now! :D